# Directory structure for types and interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I am wanting to migrate all my JS programs over to TS. I am not certain that my apps started with great directory structure to begin with, however, I want to make sure that I get it right as I migrate over to TS. My current file structure looks as follows.

```
├── src
|   ├── config
|   |   └── datastore.js
|   ├── helpers
|   |   └── helpers.js
|   ├── routers
|   |   └── slack.js
|   ├── views
|   |   ├── home.js
|   |   ├── messages.js
|   |   └── modals.js
|   └── app.js
├── package.json
├── LICENCE.md
└── README.md
```

I am wondering whether this is a good structure to have as well as where I should put my type/interface files.

Should I create new directory for types/interfaces, Should I have an interface/type file for each of my `*.js` files, I am really not sure how to manage types in my conversion.

Thank you for all of your advice or feedback in advanced.

Comment: Instead of messing about with `.d.ts` files, just convert all your `.js` files to `.ts`,..

Comment: Thanks @Keith, When I convert my files from `.js` to `.ts` if I need to create types for items in the `.ts` files should I create those types/interfaces within the original `.ts` file, or should I create a new `homeInterfaces.ts` file to store the interfaces for say the `home.ts` file.

Thanks

Comment: Just create `.ts` files, everything is then sorted.  No extra files needed,.  You can create `.d.ts` files from all your `.ts` files, but this is only normally required when you wish to ship compiled `.js` files, in theory using `.d.ts` files might be faster for `.ts` files too, but I've never had any issues with accessing types directly from `.ts` files.   VS code works really well just using `.ts` files..